# Duplicating and arranging a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list,

```
{a,b,c,d,...,z}
```

And I want to duplicate that list n times such that,

```
{a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,....z,z,z}.
```

I have found the Table function can create duplicates by appending to the end of the list. Is this the way to go and then reordering? If so, how?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Map` (or its shorthand `/@`) together with `Sequence` over the list:

```
list = {a, b, c}
Sequence[#, #, #] & /@ list
(* {a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c} *)
```

For larger amounts of repetition, that gets annoying. In that case, you can use `ConstantArray` and the remove the `List` head:

```
list = {a, b, c}
n = 5
Sequence @@ ConstantArray[#, n] & /@ list
(* {a, a, a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, c, c, c, c, c} *)
```

As J. M. mentions you can also use `Flatten` (or even `Join`) instead of `Sequence`:

```
Flatten[ConstantArray[#, n] & /@ list]
Join @@ (ConstantArray[#, n] &) /@ list
```

Comment: I'd have used `Flatten[]` myself.

Comment: @J.M. Hm yeah I considered that, but it seems more natural to me to just "expand" each element in its place in the list instead of turning it into 2D first and then flattening it back down to 1 level again, but I've added it for completeness. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 8):

```
f1 = Flatten@Transpose@ConstantArray@## &;
f2 = With[{ls = #}, Flatten[Transpose@Array[ls &, #2]]] &;
f3 = Flatten@Transpose[Table[#, {#2}]] &;
f4 = Flatten[ArrayPad[List /@ #, {{0, 0}, {0, #2 - 1}}, "Fixed"]] &;

lst = {a, b, c, d};

f1[lst, 3]
```

> {a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c, d, d, d}

```
 Equal @@ (#[lst, 3] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4})
```

> True

**Timings:**

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 1000000];
n = 3;
{t1, r1} = f1[list, n] // AbsoluteTiming;
{t2, r2} = f2[list, n] // AbsoluteTiming;
{t3, r3} = f3[list, n] // AbsoluteTiming;
{t4, r4} = f4[list, n] // AbsoluteTiming;
{t5, r5} = Flatten[ConstantArray[#, n] & /@ list] // AbsoluteTiming;
{t6, r6} = Sequence @@ ConstantArray[#, n] & /@ list // AbsoluteTiming;
{t7, r7} = Flatten@Replace[list, a_ :> Table[a, {n}], 1] // AbsoluteTiming;
{t8, r8} = Flatten[NestList[# &, #, 2] & /@ list] // AbsoluteTiming;

{t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8}
```

> {0.044306, 0.034579, 0.021672, 0.111301, 0.558783, 2.088776, 1.020894, 0.369900}

```
Equal @@ {r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8}
```

> True

Comment: Maybe you want to add a benchmark for all methods? then I would delete my answer.

Comment: @BlacKow, i will add timings in a moment.

Answer (score 3):

This one is just for fun,

```
list = ToExpression /@ Alphabet[]
Most@Fold[Riffle[#1, list, #2] &, list~Join~{dummy}, Range[2, 5]]

(* {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, 
u, v, w, x, y, z} *)

(* {a, a, a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, c, c, c, c, c, d, d, d, d, d, 
e, e, e, e, e, f, f, f, f, f, g, g, g, g, g, h, h, h, h, h, i, i, i, 
i, i, j, j, j, j, j, k, k, k, k, k, l, l, l, l, l, m, m, m, m, m, n, 
n, n, n, n, o, o, o, o, o, p, p, p, p, p, q, q, q, q, q, r, r, r, r, 
r, s, s, s, s, s, t, t, t, t, t, u, u, u, u, u, v, v, v, v, v, w, w, 
w, w, w, x, x, x, x, x, y, y, y, y, y, z, z, z, z, z} *)
```

You need the dummy variable or else `Riffle` won't put any extra `z`s on the end.

Answer (score 1):

A replacement version:

```
lst = {a, b, c, d};
Replace[lst, a_ :> Sequence[a, a, a], 1]
(* {a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c, d, d, d} *)
```

or

```
Replace[lst, a_ :> Sequence @@ Table[a, {5}], 1]
(* {a, a, a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, c, c, c, c, c, d, d, d, d, d} *)
```

or, slightly faster,

```
Flatten@Replace[lst, a_ :> Table[a, {5}], 1]
```

Comment: Another alternative: `Cases[lst, x_ :> Sequence[x, x, x, x]]`