# How to repeat each element in a list and the whole list as well?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Consider a list as

```
list={1,2,3,4};
```

I can repeat the list `n` times in this way

```
listRepeated=Flatten@Table[list, n];
```

**Question 1:** Can it be done in a faster way?

I also want to repeat each element `n` times. For example, for `n=3` the above list should become

```
listElementRepeated={1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4};
```

I can do this in this way

```
listElementRepeated=Flatten@Gather[listRepeated];
```

**Question 2:** Can it be done in a better and faster way?

Comment: This is *almost* it: `Fold[Riffle[#1, list, #2] &, list, Range[2, 3]]`

Comment: Related: (i)  [Duplicating and arranging a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113327/106) and (ii) [List creation/manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56839/106)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f1 = Join @@ {#}[[ConstantArray[1, #2]]] &;
f1[Range[4], 3]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}

```
f2 = Flatten@Transpose[{#}[[ConstantArray[1, #2]]]] &;
f2[Range[4], 3]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}

Comment: Performance wise your code is faster in both the cases (Thanks to @Henrik). I wonder why your answer hasn't got many upvotes compared to other answers.

Comment: @Majis, i wish i knew why:)

Answer (score 6):

Repeated list:

```
SeedRandom[666];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 100000}, 1000000];
n = 3;

akglr = Join @@ {list}[[ConstantArray[1, n]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
aCE = PadRight[list, n Length[list], list]; // RepeatedTiming // First
aCarl = Flatten[Outer[Times, ConstantArray[1, n], list]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
aMajis = Flatten@Developer`ToPackedArray[Table[list, n]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
aHenrik = Flatten[ConstantArray[list, n]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
aMajis0 = Flatten@Table[list, n]; // RepeatedTiming // First

aMajis0 == aMajis == aCE == aCarl == aHenrik == akglr1 == akglr2
```

> 0.0050
>
> 0.0059
>
> 0.0087
>
> 0.011
>
> 0.010
>
> 0.21

Duplicating list elements:

```
bkglr = Flatten@Transpose[{list}[[ConstantArray[1, 3]]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
bHenrik = Flatten[Transpose[ConstantArray[list, 3]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
bCarl = Flatten@Outer[Times, list, ConstantArray[1, 3]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
bJason = Fold[Riffle[#1, list, {#2, -1, #2}] &, list, Range[2, n]]; // RepeatedTiming // First

bkglr == bHenrik == bCarl == bJason
```

> 0.016
>
> 0.016
>
> 0.017
>
> 0.022
>
> True

Tests ran on a Intel 4980HQ, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3L SDRAM.

Comment: could you please re-run the first set  with `akglr = Join @@ {list}[[ConstantArray[1, n]]];`

Comment: @kglr Huh? What's going on here? I can understand that ``Developer`ToPackedArray`` has some overhead; since I can understand that part works on the ragged array `{list}`  in an instant due to pointers and lazy evaluation. Why on earth does `Join` take longer on a packed array longer than on an unpacked one? (Btw: Sorry for messing with your code; I switched to `Flatten` because; it was faster than `Join` when apllied to the packed array.)

Comment: Henrik, thank you. I too am puzzled  re `Join` v `Flatten`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my suggestion:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
repeat[list_, n_] := PadRight[list, n Length[list], list]
repeat[list, 3]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}`

```
repeat2[list_, n_] := Sequence @@ ConstantArray[#, n] & /@ list
repeat2[list, 3]
```

> `{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}`

`repeat` solves the first question, and `repeat2` solves the second question. Performance-wise `repeat` is quite a bit slower than `Flatten@ConstantArray[list, n]`, as suggested by Henrik. `repeat2` I think should be rather fast. It also has the advantage that I don't apply `Flatten` or do any such thing at the end, so it will work even if the list elements are themselves lists.

Comment: The `PadRight` method is great!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This only answers the second part of the question:

Use [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) together with [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html),

```
nmax = 10;
Fold[Riffle[#1, list, {#2, -1, #2}] &, list, Range[2, nmax]]
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of the question, perhaps a tiny bit faster than @HenrikSchumacher's answer is to use [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer):

```
list=RandomInteger[{1,100000},1000000];

r1 = Flatten[Transpose[ConstantArray[list,3]]];//RepeatedTiming
r2 = Flatten @ Outer[Times, list, Developer`ToPackedArray[{1,1,1}]]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.019, Null}
>
> {0.018, Null}
>
> True