# Duplicate each element sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of the form `{{0,0},{0,1},{1,0},{1,1}}` and I want to duplicate each of its elements, i.e. `{{0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,1},{1,1,0,0},{1,1,1,1}}`.
I saw some posts about similar issues, but none of them work for me, since they duplicate each "full" element of the list (e.g. `{0,1}` element becomes `{0,1,0,1}` instead of `{0,0,1,1}`).

For the record, I generate these lists as `Tuples[Range[cmax] - 1, n]`, where `cmax` is the local dimension (two, the 0 and the 1, for the example I gave) and `n` is the number of elements (2 for the example).

This is a related question I've found:
[How to repeat each element in a list and the whole list as well?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163814/how-to-repeat-each-element-in-a-list-and-the-whole-list-as-well)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

```
list = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};

Replace[list, x_ :> Splice[{x, x}], {2}]
Replace[list, x_ :> Sequence[x, x], {2}]
MapThread[Splice@*List, {list, list}, 2]
MapThread[Sequence, {list, list}, 2]
Join @@@ MapThread[List, {list, list}, 2]
MapThread[Riffle, {list, list}]
Riffle[#, #] & /@ list
(* {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}} *)
```

Comment: Last three work perfectly, thanks! The first two output the following message:
``Splice::string: String expected at position 1 in Splice[{0,0}]``

Comment: What version are you using? `Splice` will only work like this since version 12.1

Comment: @AlbaCL I have added two more versions as alternatives to the `Splice` versions in older versions. (I think I like them more even than the versions using the "fancier" functionality)

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};

k = 2;
Flatten[ConstantArray[#, k], {{2}, {3, 1}}] & @ list
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

```
k = 3;
Flatten[ConstantArray[#, k], {{2}, {3, 1}}] & @ list
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Another way using the [Dot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) product:

```
list.{{1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1}}

(*  {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}} *) 

list3.{{1,1,0,0},{0,0,1,1}}

(*  {{a, a, b, b}, {c, c, d, d}, {e, e, f, f}, {g, g, h, h}}  *)
```

In addition, using [Inner](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html):

```
Inner[ConstantArray, list3, {2,2},Join]

(*  {{a, a, b, b}, {c, c, d, d}, {e, e, f, f}, {g, g, h, h}}  *)

Inner[ConstantArray, list3, {3,3},Join]

(*  {{a, a, a, b, b, b}, {c, c, c, d, d, d}, {e, e, e, f, f, f}, {g, g, g, h, h, h}}  *)

Inner[ConstantArray, list, {2,2},Join]

(* {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}  *)
```

Or:

```
Inner[Times, list3, {1,1}, {#1,#1,#2,#2}&]

(*  {{a, a, b, b}, {c, c, d, d}, {e, e, f, f}, {g, g, h, h}}  *)

Inner[Times, list, {1,1}, {#1,#1,#2,#2}&]

(*  {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}  *)
```

where

```
list = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};

list3={{a,b},{c,d},{e,f},{g,h}}
```

**Edit**

Use [Apply](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) (at level 1):

```
{#1,#1,#2,#2}&@@@list3 

(*  {{a, a, b, b}, {c, c, d, d}, {e, e, f, f}, {g, g, h, h}}  *)
```

Comment: And, of course, `Cases[list, {x_,y_} :> {x,x,y,y}]`

Comment: In addition, `ArrayReduce[Flatten[{#,#},{{2,1}}]&,list3,2]`

Comment: Apply, slightly shorter: `{#1,##,#2}&@@@list`

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};
```

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[list, {a_, b_} -> {a, a, b, b}]
```

{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};
```

---

Using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, s : {a_, b_}, ___} :> Join @@ Thread@{s, s}]

(*{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Also using `ArrayPad`

```
list = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};

ArrayPad[#, 1, "Fixed"] & /@ list
```

> `{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SubstitutionSystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubstitutionSystem.html)

For example:

```
rules = {1 -> {1, 1}, 0 -> {0, 0}};
v = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};
Join @@@ SubstitutionSystem[rules, v, 1][[2]]
```

yields:

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Function[x,Delete[#, 0] & /@ ({#, #} & /@ x)] /@ YourList
```

Let's have try :

```
In[1] Function[x,Delete[#, 0] & /@ ({#, #} & /@ x)] /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}

Out[1] {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

Done!

Comment: (+1) Also `Map[Splice@{#,#}&, lst, {2}]`