# list-array construction

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create the list `ix={1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4}`

I can do

```
L=4;
ix = ConstantArray[0, Length[L]^2]
k = 0;
For[i = 1, i <= Length[ix], i++, If[Mod[i, L] == 1, k = k + 1, k]; ix[[i]] = k;]

ix
(* output *)
{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}
```

But I don't like it. Is there a more "Mathematica"-way to do it?

Comment: Try:  total = 5;
Flatten@Table[n {1, 1, 1, 1}, {n, 1, total}]

Comment: So it’s just an array of 1, 2, 3, & 4, each with 4 instances?

Comment: @CATrevillian For  this example, yes. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Related: (i)  [How to repeat each element in a list and the whole list as well?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163814/106), (ii) [Duplicating and arranging a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113327/106), (iii) [List creation/manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56839/106)

Comment: This is [OEIS A002265](https://oeis.org/A002265), for reference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you see from the comments and answers, the natural way to do it in *Mathematica* is to create a 2D array and then flatten it. A couple more examples of that approach:

```
Flatten[Table[i, {i, 4}, 4]]

Flatten[Array[# &, {4, 4}]]
```

For this specific case you could also do something like:

```
Ceiling[Range[16]/4]
```

Comment: The `Ceiling` example is stupendous. With `Apply` that is likely a `code-golf` winning answer!

Answer (score 13):

You can also interpret this as an outer product:

```
Outer[Times, Range[4], ConstantArray[1, 4]] // Flatten
{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the 4-argument form of `Array`:

```
Array[# &, {4, 4}, 1, Flatten @* List]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}
> ```

```
Array[Range @ 4 &, 4, 1, Sort @* Join]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}
> ```

```
Array[{1, 0, 0, 0} &, 4, 1, Accumulate @* Join]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}
> ```

And few additional methods:

```
Round[1/2 + 6 Range[16]/25]

Sort @ Mod[Range @ 16, 4, 1]

Join @@ Table @@@ Table[{i, 4}, {i, 4}]

1 + ⌊Most @ Subdivide[4, 16]⌋

Join @@ Accumulate @ Table[1, 4, 4]

Accumulate @ Upsample[{1, 1, 1, 1}, 4] (*thanks: Simon Woods *)

⌈ArrayResample[Range@4, 16, {"Bin", 1}]⌉

Internal`RepetitionFromMultiplicity @ Thread[{Range @ 4, 4}]
```

Comment: I like the `Accumulate` one. You could also have `Accumulate@Upsample[{1, 1, 1, 1}, 4]`

Comment: Thank you @Simon. I did try to torture `Upsample` and `ArrayResample`  to produce the desired result; wrapping with `Accumulate` did not occur to me.

Answer (score 10):

This uses an anonymous function in tandem with `ConstantArray` and `Range` to do what you want:

```
ConstantArray[#,4]&/@Range@4//Flatten
```

> {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4}

Comment: Also `Flatten[ConstantArray[Range[4], 4], {2, 1}]`

Comment: `Flatten@Transpose@ConstantArray[Range@4, 4]`

Comment: @SimonWoods that use of `Flatten` really shows off it’s similarity to `Transpose`! Very cool.

Answer (score 7):

**Riffle/Nest**

```
Range[4]//Nest[Riffle[#,#]&,#,2]&
```

Alternatively:

```
Range[4]//Riffle[#,#]&//Riffle[#,#]&
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}

**BitShiftRight**

After the neat `Ceiling` [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238298/106) by Simon Woods:

```
1+Table[BitShiftRight[n,2], {n, 0, 15}]
```

Alternatively:

```
1+BitShiftRight[#,2]&@Range[0,15]
```

**IntegerPart**

From the documentation for [BitShiftRight->Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BitShiftRight.html#DetailsAndOptions), and the relationship between `BitShiftRight` and `IntegerPart`:

```
1+IntegerPart@Table[n/4, {n, 0, 15}]
```

Alternatively:

```
1+IntegerPart[Range[0,15]/4]
```

**Cases**

```
Cases[Range[4], x_:> Splice@{x,x,x,x}]
```

(Originally a comment)

Answer (score 7):

Another way:

```
Quotient[Range@16, 4, -3]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}

Answer (score 6):

```
CoefficientList[Series[x^4/((1 - x) (1 - x^4)), {x, 0, 19}], x][[5 ;;]]
```

.

```
LinearRecurrence[{1, 0, 0, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, 16]
```

.

```
Table[Length@IntegerPartitions[k - 1, All, {1, 4}], {k, 16}]
```

Answer (score 5):

A couple more:

```
PadRight[{Range@4}\[Transpose], {4, 4}, "Fixed"] // Flatten
Outer[# &, #, #] &@Range@4 // Flatten
```

*Update — Additional ones:*

```
Range[4] SparseArray[{}, {4, 4}, 1] // Flatten
With[{p = ConstantArray[1, 4]},
  SparseArray[{Band[p] -> 1}, Length[p] p]@"NonzeroPositions" // Flatten
  ]
TensorProduct[Range@4, ConstantArray[1, {4}]] // Flatten
```

Answer (score 4):

Recommending:

```
Quotient[Range[4, 19], 4] (* ~1.759μs *)
```

#### Benchmark

```
Quotient[Range@16, 4, -3] (* ~2.554μs *)
Outer[Times, Range[4], ConstantArray[1, 4]] // Flatten (* ~2.573μs *)

Internal`RepetitionFromMultiplicity @ Thread[{Range @ 4, 4}] (* ~3.498μs *)
Flatten@Transpose@ConstantArray[Range@4, 4] (* ~3.527μs *)
Flatten[ConstantArray[Range[4], 4], {2, 1}] (* ~3.701μs *)
Flatten[Table[i, {i, 4}, 4]] (* ~3.919μs *)
Range[4]//Riffle[#,#]&//Riffle[#,#]& (* ~3.928μs *)

1+BitShiftRight[#,2]&@Range[0,15] (* ~4.191μs *)
Range[4]//Nest[Riffle[#,#]&,#,2]& (* ~4.411μs *)
Array[{1, 0, 0, 0} &, 4, 1, Accumulate @* Join] (* ~4.747μs *)

Sort@Mod[Range@16, 4, 1] (* ~5.506μs *)
Array[Range @ 4 &, 4, 1, Sort @* Join] (* ~5.655μs *)
Range[4] SparseArray[{}, {4, 4}, 1] // Flatten (* ~5.853μs *)
Outer[# &, #, #] &@Range@4 // Flatten (* ~5.974μs *)

Join @@ Accumulate @ Table[1, 4, 4] (* ~6.300μs *)
Flatten[Array[# &, {4, 4}]] (* ~6.833μs *)

PadRight[{Range@4}\[Transpose], {4, 4}, "Fixed"] // Flatten (* ~7.013μs *)
Join @@ Table @@@ Table[{i, 4}, {i, 4}] (* ~7.589μs *)

Cases[Range[4], x_:> Splice@{x,x,x,x}] (* ~8.041μs *)
Array[# &, {4, 4}, 1, Flatten @* List] (* ~8.519μs *)

1+Table[BitShiftRight[n,2], {n, 0, 15}] (* ~9.554μs *)

ConstantArray[#,4]&/@Range@4//Flatten (* ~10.058μs *)
Ceiling[Range[16]/4] (* ~11.210μs *)
1 + ⌊Most @ Subdivide[4, 16]⌋ (* ~13.635μs *)
1+IntegerPart@Table[n/4, {n, 0, 15}] (* ~18.513μs *)
TensorProduct[Range@4, ConstantArray[1, {4}]] // Flatten (* ~18.924μs *)
Round[1/2 + 6 Range[16]/25] (* ~22.859μs *)
Table[Length@IntegerPartitions[k - 1, All, {1, 4}], {k, 16}] (* ~58.000μs *)

Accumulate @ Upsample[{1, 1, 1, 1}, 4] (* ~194.7μs with 6k runs *)
LinearRecurrence[{1, 0, 0, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, 16] (* ~336.2μs with 5k runs *)
CoefficientList[Series[x^4/((1 - x) (1 - x^4)), {x, 0, 19}], x][[5 ;;]] (* ~529.7μs with 18k runs *)

⌈ArrayResample[Range@4, 16, {"Bin", 1}]⌉ (* ~1620μs with 1k runs *)
```

Each repeated 30k times unless otherwise stated. One may conclude that, in *Mathematica*,

- simple algebra generally works faster
- more arguments specified $\neq$ faster
- `/` division drags, compared to `Quotient`
- bit operations aren't as fast as they're in *C*
- `/@` is slow, if `@` can spread
- ...

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}, x] // Expand
(*    8256 - x*536645091/20020 + x^2*1798275487/48510 -
      x^3*128580216461/4365900 + x^4*25293360053/1663200 -
      x^5*8745144029/1603800 + x^6*768388933/544320 -
      x^7*315030731/1166400 + x^8*92080313/2381400 -
      x^9*237559139/57153600 + x^10*30277/90720 -
      x^11*50569/2566080 + x^12*12427/14968800 -
      x^13*27557/1167566400 + x^14*17/41912640 - x^15/314344800    *)

Array[f, 16]
(*    {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4}    *)
```